# How to find a grid element by content, rather than grid number in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, grid

I have a website in which the grid numbers don't match up with the shown primary key.
For example, the key will tell the user that an element in the table is number 42, when it's only the 30th element in the grid, due to permission-based number skipping.
What is the best way to select based on the primary key, rather than the grid number in selenium?

Clarification:
say my grid looks like this:

`6   Ice Cream
11  Hot Dog
24  Cheeseburger
25  Double Cheeseburger
26  Salad`

Ice cream can be selected through 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*grid-0");`
Hot Dog = grid-1
etc...

What would be the best way to select icecream by the contents of its key (6) instead?

I can iterate through the entire grid using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*grid-0")).getText().contains("6");
```

but then I have the issue of locating every element with a 6 in it, instead of just ice cream, and I have to traverse the entire page to find it, which is really inefficient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this can be any helpful.

```
driver.findElement( By.xpath( "//*[contains(text(), '6 ')]" ) );
```

Comment: Ah, clever, using the space afterwards, however I still feel as though that may register the string '16'. I will try appending a space before AND after though, and I feel as though that's sufficient! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wound up going with the following:
`driver.findElement(By.linkText("regexp:.* 6 *")).click();`

Thanks to [Ravi MCA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1588361/ravi-mca) for helping me get to this conclusion!

EDIT: This solution only works for selenium IDE, apparently webdriver interprets regexp:. as a literal.